# Split list into multiple groups based on co-existence rules

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, set-theory

I would like to create groups of strings (or objects) based on 'exclusion' rules - i.e. which item can exist or 'talk' to other items

For example, lets say I have a list of names:

```py
names = ['proxy', 's1', 's2', 'queue', 'w1']
```

Then I say, `'proxy'` can talk with `'s1'` and `'s2'` but `'s1'` cannot talk to `'s2'` (and this should be mutual).
I can represent these rules and names as a list of objects:

```
proxy = {'name': 'proxy', 'exclude': [q, 'w1']}
s1 = {'name': 's1', 'exclude': ['s2', 'w1']}
s2 = {'name': 's2', 'exclude': ['s1', 'w1']}
q = {'name': 'queue', 'exclude': ['proxy']}
w1 = {'name': 'w1', 'exclude': ['proxy', 's1', 's2']}
```

Here I would expect to end up with 5 groups:

```
[
  ['proxy', 's1'],
  ['proxy', 's2'],
  ['s1', 'queue'],
  ['s2', 'queue'],
  ['queue', 'w1']
]
```

I have tried to use `set.difference`on the full list of names for each 'exclusion' and then remove any sets that are equal, but this is not enough, for example for the first item - 'proxy', I would end up with a set of ['proxy', 's1', 's2'] but ofc 's1' and 's2' cannot be together.

I am stumped for a solution to this problem, but I having a feeling it is or is similar to common mathematical/set theory problems?

Extra Info:
As mentioned nicely by @MrFuppes connections are bidirectional (i.e if X excludes Z then Z should exclude X) and this should be assumed and if possible inferred. This is to make it simpler for the user so they do not have to explicitly state both rules. 
It may be that my 'rule schema' is not the optimal way of gathering the data from the user to solve the problem and if there is a more optimal way I am all for it.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not the most beautiful Python ever written, but it will do the trick. I took the liberty to collect the rules in a rules dictionary and renamed q to queue for consistency. If that's a problem, we'll find a workaround

```
rules = {'proxy':{'name': 'proxy', 'exclude': ['queue', 'w1']},
         's1': {'name': 's1', 'exclude': ['s2', 'w1']},
         's2':{'name': 's2', 'exclude': ['s1', 'w1']},
         'queue': {'name': 'queue', 'exclude': ['proxy']},
         'w1': {'name': 'w1', 'exclude': ['proxy', 's1', 's2']}}
names = ['proxy', 's1', 's2', 'queue', 'w1']
```

And now for the code itself. I'm first deep-copying the rules dict because I'll be adding connections already listed as excludes and don't want to mess with the original rule set. The rest is pretty straight forward, so I'll not comment too much on it: get all allowed names by dropping the connector itself and all blocked connections, add each connection to the connection list and add the connector as a blocked element to all connections affected to avoid doubling entries

```
import copy
conns = []
working_rules = copy.deepcopy(rules)
for item in names:
    tmp_names = names.copy()
    tmp_names.remove(item)
    allowed = [el for el in tmp_names if el not in working_rules[item]['exclude']]
    for el in allowed:
        conns.append([item, el])
        working_rules[el]['exclude'].append(item)
```

Comment: good stuff. Modifying the schema for the initial data is totally possible. I have full control over it so we can go for the most optimal solution (most optimal being the schema that is easiest for the user to use, not necessarily the most performant or concise)

Comment: One thing I note about this solution is that it is non-optimal since it always creates groups in pairs. For example, suppose we have a list of 3 names and non exclusions. The optimal solution would be that there is 1 group which contains all 3 names. This solution would give 3 groups for each pairing and each name would be a member of 2 groups.

Comment: That is true. I didn't design the code to support arbitrary size groups given the example only had pairs in it. I'll think about it some more when I have any spare time at my hands

Comment: Didn't take as long as expected :D connection pairs returned by my "stage 1 solution" can be interpreted as edges in a graph (the connectors being the vertices) and your problem is equivalent to finding the connected components of said graph. [This google search result](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/connected-components-in-an-undirected-graph/) has a Python 3 implementation that you should be able to leverage

Comment: @LukasThaler: nice way to approach this (referring to your last comment)! The problem I see with that is that the "graph" is neither undirected nor strongly connected, right?

Comment: @MrFuppes The "graph" we have at hand can be viewed as undirected. Given we don't have `['proxy', 's1']` and simultaneously `['s1', 'proxy']` in our connection set, any element in the connection set represents an edge between two connectors in the graph. If the result is connected or not depends on the rules imposed on the system, but for finding connected components (as the "components" implies), that is not necessary

Answer (score 3):

Given the expected output, the input rules are "incomplete", meaning mutuality of exclusions has to be inferred - as Lukas Thaler shows in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58874571/10197418). The inferred exclusion rules will then depend on the order of the input `names`. A simplified version using `sets` might look as follows:

```py
excl = {'proxy': ['queue', 'w1'],
        's1': ['s2', 'w1'],
        's2': ['s1', 'w1'],
        'queue': ['proxy'],
        'w1': ['proxy', 's1', 's2']}

names = ['proxy', 's1', 's2', 'queue', 'w1']

result = []
for n in names:
    for i in set(names)-set(excl[n] + [n]):
        result.append([n, i])
        excl[i].append(n)

print(result)

# [['proxy', 's1'],
#  ['proxy', 's2'],
#  ['s1', 'queue'],
#  ['s2', 'queue'],
#  ['queue', 'w1']]
```

Updated exclusion rules would now be

```
{'proxy': ['queue', 'w1'],
    's1': ['s2', 'w1', 'proxy'],
    's2': ['s1', 'w1', 'proxy'],
 'queue': ['proxy', 's1', 's2'],
    'w1': ['proxy', 's1', 's2', 'queue']}
```

---

**EDIT #1**

If I'm not mistaken, a priori assuming bidirectional communication would make things easier (and also make for a clear definition of rules in the first place). Example: Given objects `a, b, c`, one might say that `a` should communicate with `b` and vice versa. `a` should also communicate with `c` but *not* vice versa. `b` should not communicate with `c` and vice versa. That would make

```py
objs = ['a', 'b', 'c']
excl = {'a': [], 
        'b': ['c'],
        'c': ['a', 'b']}

connections = [[o, i] for o in objs for i in set(objs)-set(excl[o] + [o])]
print(connections)
# [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'a']]
```

---

**EDIT #2**

Simplifying the connections list could be then done by sorting into bi- and unidirectional components, e.g.

```py
conn_grouped = {'bidirectional': [], 'unidirectional': []}
for c in connections:
    rev_c = list(reversed(c))
    if rev_c not in connections:
        conn_grouped['unidirectional'].append(c)
    if rev_c in connections and not rev_c in conn_grouped['bidirectional']:
        conn_grouped['bidirectional'].append(c)

print(conn_grouped)
# {'bidirectional': [['a', 'b']], 'unidirectional': [['a', 'c']]}
```

If the number of communicating nodes gets large, it might be required to find a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: this is cool. In fact, being able to infer the mutuality would be a benefit, making it simpler for a user to state their rules.

Comment: @jramm actually, this bugs me a bit about this problem - since the rules at the end basically say that all connections are unidirectional. Bidirectionality is excluded by the rule inferance scheme used here I think. Assuming bidirectionality in the first place and deliberately excluding it by a complete set of rules might be more generally applicable.

Comment: agreed. Any idea for a better rule schema? my main idea was to make it so that the user does not need to work out what 'groups' they need, but to allow them to (as simply as possible) say 'X cannot talk to Y and Z' and 'Z can also not talk to K'. Bidrectionality should be assumed so they dont have to explicitly state it

Comment: I imagine we can remove the dependency on name order by inferring the extra exclusion rules in an initial loop. This will half the performance, but it is largely negligible due to the relatively small size of list (I dont anticipate more than 10-20 items)

Comment: @jramm, made an edit to show what I mean. Hope I got the point ;-)

Comment: still, I'm having a hard time thinking about a way how to give a user a good impression of all the dependencies/implications if he/she adds objects and/or introduces new rules

Comment: Another problem - like the other solution, here we will always generate groups in pairs and thats it, which is not totally optimal. For example, suppose we have a list of 3 names and no exclusions. The optimal solution would be that there is 1 group which contains all 3 names. This solution would give 3 groups for each pairing and each name would be a member of 2 groups

Comment: @jramm you mean like separating bi- and unidirectional relations (would basically make 2 groups)?